# Using Data Variable in Google Analytics Report of an Google Optimize Experiment

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-optimize

**Use Case**

- I have a customer id inside a dataLayer variable.
- I have run an experiment on Google Optimize.
- I would like to see which customer id saw which experiment.

Thank you and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the customer id in an user-scoped custom dimension? Though the scope might depend on how you want to set up your experiment, will one customer only see one variant or multiple?

Once you have the customer id in a CD, you can [look at your Optimize data in GA](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/7364397?hl=en) and create a custom report along with the variant that they saw.